# Collapsible sidebar with React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to build a page with a collapsible sidebar using React Bootstrap.
Something similar to the [Bootstrap Dashboard example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/dashboard/).
The difference is that I don't want a Navbar on the top of the page. Just the Sidebar and the MainContentArea.

With the code below, when the Sidebar collapses the toggle button is shown (screens smaller than medium size), but when I click on the button the Sidebar is not expanded.

Any help is appreciated.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Icon from '../../assets/Icon';
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';


const Sidebar = () => (
    <Nav id="sidebarMenu" className="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-white h-100 sidebar pr-0 collapse">
      <div className="flex-column mt-5 pl-3">
        <img src={require('../../assets/logo-pcp.svg')} className="img-fluid" alt='Imagem do Logo'/>
      </div>
      <Nav className="flex-column mt-5">
        <LinkContainer exact to="/" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link className="mt-3"><Icon icon="Criação" />  Criação</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/em-andamento" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link className="mt-3"><Icon icon="Em andamento" />  Em andamento</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/em-andamento/por-coordenadoria" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link><Icon icon="Sem ícone" />  Por Coordenadoria</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/em-andamento/percentual-execucao" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link><Icon icon="Sem ícone" />  Percentual de execução</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/em-andamento/indicadores" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link><Icon icon="Sem ícone" />  Indicadores</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/em-andamento/sem-atualizacao" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link><Icon icon="Sem ícone" />  Sem atualização</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="/conclusao" activeClassName="active">
          <Nav.Link className="mt-3"><Icon icon="Conclusão" />  Conclusão</Nav.Link>
        </LinkContainer>
      </Nav>
    </Nav>
);

export default Sidebar;


import React from 'react';
import { Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';

const MainArea = (props) => (
  <Col className="col-md-9 col-lg-10 d-md-block bg-light pt-6 px-6">
    <Row>
      <Nav className="navbar navbar-light flex-md-nowrap p-0">
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="sidebarMenu" className="d-md-none"/>
      </Nav>
      <Col>
        {props.children}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Col>
);

export default MainArea;
```